# sorting a data frame without loop

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame created out of a TDM. I want to find the top 10 terms (listed as rownames) for each document (listed as column headers). Is there a way to do this without a loop in R?
For example, the below table I want to see the top 3 terms for each column along with the terms and their value in the column.

```
            X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10 X11 X12 X13 X14 X15 X16
will        10 18 19 36 27 53 21 17 15  59  15  21  35  19  30  27
poor         3 11  0  4  0  0  2  2  2   7   2   5   9   3   2   8
country     12 10  4  8  9  1  6 15  8  15   8  10   8   2  15   9
now          1 10  3  5  5  2  4  1  0   9   0   8   5   1  11   3
```

Comment: You can probably use `order()` but without more details on your data, it will be difficult to help you more.

Comment: If there is no reproducible, it is hard to help.

Comment: `arrange()` from the `dplyr` can also do the job.

Comment: thanks @NikMuhammadNaim but wouldnt arrange also require a loop, I dont need multi level sort but find top values and rownames for each column

Comment: If you can also add the result you want, it would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `apply` to sort each column, and return a list containing a named vector of the top `n` elements in that column:

```r
set.seed(1)

x <- replicate(3, rpois(5, 10))
rownames(x) <- letters[1:5]
colnames(x) <- paste0("X", seq_len(ncol(x)))
x
#>   X1 X2 X3
#> a  8 12  8
#> b 10 11  2
#> c  7  9  8
#> d 11 14 10
#> e 14 11  7

n <- 3
apply(x, 2, function(x) list(sort(x)[seq_len(n)]))
#> $X1
#> $X1[[1]]
#>  c  a  b 
#>  7  8 10 
#> 
#> 
#> $X2
#> $X2[[1]]
#>  c  b  e 
#>  9 11 11 
#> 
#> 
#> $X3
#> $X3[[1]]
#> b e a 
#> 2 7 8
```

Created on 2018-03-16 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: thanks this worked perfect. couldn't find this response on quite a few search results hence had to post.  thanks again.